# Install new package without removing old ones

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt

I am using virtualbox5.1 that require libcurl3. When I tried to install curl,  apt want to install libcurl4 and remove libcurl3 with virtualbox5.1. So how to install curl without removing libcurl3 and virtualbox5.1?

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libcurl4
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libcurl3 virtualbox-5.1
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  curl libcurl4
```

P.S using Ubuntu 18.04 and I used URLs from Ubuntu Xenial in sources list to download libcurl3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `bionic` repo for Ubuntu 18.04, not the `xenial` repo, which is for Ubuntu 16.04.

You can see that the correct dependency on `libcurl4` is present in https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/dists/bionic/contrib/binary-amd64/Packages

But the `xenial` repository shows a dependency on `libcurl3`: https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/dists/xenial/contrib/binary-amd64/Packages

The apt repository line should read as follows:

```
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bionic contrib
```

You can find this somewhere in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` or in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.  It could be in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list`.